# Where did "shabat shalom" come from?

Tags: shabbat, translation, words, hebrew

What is the source for the greeting "שבת שלום"?

Where is it earliest attested in print?

What does it mean?

Comment: Rabbi Akiva Eiger 271

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67611

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's at least as old as the *Sh'la* ([around 1600](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Horowitz)), according to *Taame Haminhagim, kuntres acharon* 94 to paragraph 396, which says in the *Sh'la*'s name, via the *Baer Hetev* OC 307:2: "Someone visiting his friend on *Shabas* should not say, e.g., 'good morning' as on a weekday, but rather '*shabas shalom*' or '*shabas tov*', to fulfill '*zachor es yom hashabas*'."

It may, of course, be older; perhaps someone else has more info.

Answer (score 17):

It is prescribed in שער הכוונות (*Sha'ar Hakavanos*, published in the sixteenth century) in the 7th paragraph [here](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%91)) to announce it loudly upon arriving home on Friday night for the reasons mentioned by [msh210](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5450/1059).

Comment: This is prior to the Shala.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general precept to ask the well-being of another person. This is known as [שאילת שלום](http://www.aspaklaria.info/300_SHIN/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D.htm), asking of ‘shalom’. For example in [Berachot 9:5:](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.9.5)

> וְהִתְקִינוּ, שֶׁיְּהֵא אָדָם שׁוֹאֵל אֶת שְׁלוֹם חֲבֵרוֹ בַּשֵּׁם, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (רות ב) וְהִנֵּה בֹעַז בָּא מִבֵּית לֶחֶם, וַיֹּאמֶר לַקּוֹצְרִים יְיָ עִמָּכֶם, וַיֹּאמְרוּ לוֹ, יְבָרֶכְךָ יְיָ
>
> And they corrected this, that one shall inquire after the peace of his friend with the Name [of God], as it says, “And behold, Boaz came from Bethlehem and said to the harvesters, ‘God be with you’, and they said to him, ‘God bless you.’” (Ruth 2:4) (Sefaria translation)

Or in [Avot 4:15:](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.4.15)

> רַבִּי מַתְיָא בֶן חָרָשׁ אוֹמֵר, הֱוֵי מַקְדִּים בִּשְׁלוֹם כָּל אָדָם.
>
> Rabbi Mattia ben Charash says: Be the first to greet every person.

It is the logical conclusion that is this the source of Shabbat Shalom, based on a statement in Yerushalmi (Shabbat 15:3 (78b), quoted in Tosafot Shababat 113b, Aruch Hashulchan 307):

> אמר רבי חנינא מדוחק התירו לשאול שלום בשבת
>
> Rebbi Chanina said: Asking shalom on Shabbat was permitted but with difficulty.

The statement refers to how one should change the manner in which one speaks on Shabbat, and to only speak sparingly and holily.

Comment: Interesting adduction! Can you spell out what the expected greeting/manner would have been before applying the _Y'rushalmi_ and what it turned out to be after?