# Do we say "shabbat shalom" on Tisha b'Av that falls on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, mourning-aveilus, tisha-bav, social-convention

Yesterday I said "shabbat shalom" to someone and he said we don't do that on Tisha b'Av that falls on Shabbat.  I thought that Shabbat trumps the day (and that's why we move the other observances).  Neither of us knew a source, and it hasn't come up yet in [9 be-Av on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/9-be-av-on-shabbos) .

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5445/where-did-shabat-shalom-come-from

Comment: I think your friend was mistaken. Otherwise, we also wouldn't eat meat on a Shabbat that coincided with the 9th of Av, nor drink wine. If the prohibition of eating meat and drinking wine are overridden, then certainly the prohibition of greeting somebody would be overridden. I don't have any sources for that.

Comment: As I outlined in my answer in the linked question, private forms of mourning remain forbidden (at least for Ashkenazim). I speculate that if not saying Shabbat Shalom would be noticeable, then you must say it; otherwise you may not. Note that according to this it would be permitted to respond to someone in all (?) cases.

Comment: @ShimonbM I don't follow. Meat and wine is for the most part a minhag whereas greeting someone is halacha. Furthermore, the meat and wine are being consumed at a seudat mitzva whereas I know of no particular mitzva to greet someone on shabbat. Finally as I outline above, greeting is often a private thing and is not so noticeable when skipped (particularly if all that is being skipped is a [particular formulation](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12690/759)) whereas skipping meat and wine on Shabbat is quite public and noticeable.

Comment: @DoubleAA, re "As I outlined.... I speculate....": Sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Shulchan Aruch (i will try to find the exact place) says that on a shabbos thats also tisha b'av you should mour n for the bais hamikdash b'tzinah (privately) verbally not saying good shabbos/shabbat shalom is not exactly private and he was doing it because the day was tisha b'av. Although he might have a special minhag (custom) to not say good shabbos/shabbat shalom, you might want to ask your friend about that.