# Shavuah Tov or A Gutte Vuch on Motzai Shabbos

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, blessing, motzei-shabbos

What is the earliest reference or source for wishing Shavuah Tov or A Gutte Vuch on Motzai Shabbos?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5445